# SQL Server 2016 CSV file import

Tags: sql-server

I have a table dump in CSV format. Using SQL Server Management Studio I can import that CSV file, but the problem is I can not set a column as primary key.

My CSV file/ table has column and I want to set `PARETNT_NAME` as primary while importing.

```
PARENT_NAME | QUANTITY | COMPONENT_NAME
```

Please guide me how to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f5a602ac-3f46-46c2-81f4-ec756fb8fc0b/dtswizard-how-to-generate-primary-keys-during-import-from-a-flat-file?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the import there is a step where you pick the table to import to. As part of that you can manually define the SQL `CREATE TABLE` statement. I would assume you could modify that to specify the primary key. But I haven't ever tried to do this.

However, unless you have a specific reason to do this before the import, I would just use an `ALTER TABLE` statement to modify the column to be not NULL and  set it as the primary key. To me that just seems easier.